# How to run Gcov/Lcov for a diff file in the source tree?

Tags: gcov, lcov

How to use `lcov --diff` option to generate code coverage report for the diff of changes in a source view? I have a source view and i am able to generate lcov log file and html report for few of the modules in the source view. But, i am looking for an option to do a code coverage report for the diff of changes introduced in a source tree. I came across `lcov --diff` option. Could some one guide me how to use this option? Since i am facing no difference using this option to generate code coverage.
Following are the steps tried:

- Generate code coverage data (`.info` file) without any modifications in the source tree.
- Modify the source tree.
- Take a diff file with `-u` option.
- Generate code coverage data again with `--diff` option . For eg. `--diff <.info file>`

Comment: For posterity, this link might be relevant: https://sourceforge.net/p/ltp/mailman/message/24604076/